# Iframe with popup to center on parent frame

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, modalpopups

Basically all I want to do is have the modal popup from within the iframe to center on the entire page instead of just the iframe... How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this easily.  Elements that exist in the IFrame are bound to the IFrame.

I would suggest making the modal a part of the Parent and not a part of the IFrame

Answer (score 0):

short answer: you can't
long answer: if both documents are on the same domain in the same zone, you can call back from the iframe to the parent document and have IT initiate the popup but this will ONLY work on same domain/zone using `parent.document`